# Scheduler Log shows "The request has exceeded the allowable time limit Tag: cfhttp" despite hard-coded "requestTimeout"

Tags: http, coldfusion, timeout, coldfusion-11

I have four scripts that request an external API via `CFHTTP`. For each of these templates, I have the following line of code at the top of each CFM file:

`setting requestTimeout=299;`

In the scheduler.log, I am seeing the following:

> "Information","DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-8","04/15/19","22:35:00",,"Task default.WSC2 - Data - Import - Inventory triggered."
>   "Information","DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-7","04/15/19","22:35:00",,"Task default.WSC2 - Data - Import - Orders triggered."
>   "Information","DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4","04/15/19","22:35:00",,"Task default.WSC2 - Data - Import - Products triggered."
>   "Information","DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-9","04/15/19","22:35:00",,"Task default.WSC2 - Data - Import - Shipments triggered."
>   "Error","DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-9","04/15/19","22:36:00",,"The request has exceeded the allowable time limit Tag: cfhttp "
>   "Error","DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4","04/15/19","22:36:00",,"The request has exceeded the allowable time limit Tag: cfhttp "
>   "Error","DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-7","04/15/19","22:36:00",,"The request has exceeded the allowable time limit Tag: cfhttp "
>   "Error","DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-8","04/15/19","22:36:00",,"The request has exceeded the allowable time limit Tag: cfhttp "

These log entries seem to indicate that the `CFHTTP` request is timing out before the `requestTimeout` value is met.

Why is this happening? Do individual `CFHTTP` requests have their own timeouts?

Comment: Yes `cfhttp` does have it's own timeout setting. Are these `cfhttp` requests part of your scheduled job or are they the requests to launch the job itself?

Comment: @Miguel-F wow, I could not find this documented anywhere. The cfhttp calls are in the code of the requests - not part of the scheduled job itself.

Comment: It's there in the documentation, [cfdocs](https://cfdocs.org/cfhttp) and [adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-g-h/cfhttp.html). When you added the attribute did it extend the timeout on your `cfhttp` calls?  It should.